# php file_get_contents - AFTER javascript executes

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

basically, I am trying to scrape webpages with php but I want to do so after the initial javascript on a page executes - I want access to the DOM after initial ajax requests, etc... is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is a bit ambiguous. If you can post some trial code, we'll get a clearer picture.

Comment: I think OP wants to grab the contents of a web page, and if it contains JS, it should be executed as if the page was opened in a browser.

Comment: i'm using Simple HTML Dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm to scrape webpages, but so many webpages today are dynamic and I'd like the initial javascript to execute before grabbing the code... if this makes any sense!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server side browser that can execute JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142271/server-side-browser-that-can-execute-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Scraping a site gives you whatever the server responds with to the HTTP request that you make (from which the "initial" state of the DOM tree is derived, if that content is HTML). It cannot take into account the "current" state of the DOM after it has been modified by Javascript.

Comment: To extend this, JavaScript is a client-side language. It is executed once the page has been received by the browser. PHP is not a browser. In fact, PHP doesn't care about DOM either. It receives data which may or may not be in the form of XML, and you can do with it what you want.

Comment: any hacks around this? load the page in an iframe and then somehow grab the code? and simple libraries that could (attempt to) execute it somewhere along the line? i know these are probably all "no's" but I'm just trying to figure out any way to get the latest data for pages that load dynamically (such as news sites)

Comment: @JustinKrause: You would have to embed a [Javascript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine#JavaScript_engines) to the program of your choice, which would (I believe, but am not sure) immediately exclude PHP as a programming language. In any case it would be orders of magnitude harder than `file_get_contents`. Plus, are you sure your use case would be legal?

Comment: it should be legal - just as legal as scraping pages in the first place, I'd assume! it seems like it's probably beyond an amateur php guy (me)... dang! if anyone has clues to the basic system google and others use to scrape dynamic pages, I'd love to know more.  anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm revising this answer because there are now several projects that do a really good job of this:

- **2020 update**: [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) is a Node.js library that can control a Chromium browser, with experimental support for Firefox also.
- **2020 update**: [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) is a Node.js library that can control multiple browsers.

You need to install Node.js and write JavaScript code to interact with both of these projects.  Especially with `async` and `await` they work quite well, and you can use any Node.js/npm modules in your code.

There are also other projects like Selenium but I wouldn't recommend them.

<s>- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless version of WebKit, and there are some helpful wrappers such as [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).</s>

<s>- [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) which is a wrapper over [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) written in Javascript (Node.js).</s>

<s>You need to write JavaScript code to interact with both of these projects.  I like Zombie.js better so far, since it is easier to set up, and you can use any Node.js/npm modules in your code.</s>

---

Old answer:

<s>No, there's no way to do that.  You'd have to emulate a full browser environment inside PHP.  I don't know of anyone who is doing this kind of scraping except Google, and it's far from comprehensive.</s>

Instead, you should use Firebug or another web debugging tool to find the request (or sequence of requests) that generates the data you're actually interested in.  Then, use PHP to perform only the needed request(s).

Comment: @JonathanM have a look at my comment above

Comment: What's the latest server-side tool(s) that can be used for this ? phantomjs is archived as development is suspended.

Comment: @anjanesh try Puppeteer or Playwright. I updated the answer.