# PHP - How to get Network Contents That appears in Chrome using file_get_contents with PHP

Tags: php, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I go to a website in Chrome, one of the things that is loaded in the network tab of the ChromeDev Tools is this JSON file.

I want to be able to get this JSON file with file_get_contents; but that only brings back the HTML of the webpage.

If I right click on this I can see the request headers and options to copy as cURL cmd. Does anyone know how to get this from PHP?

Comment: So when you visit a website, some (i think) javascript loads a JSON file in a background? And you are trying to get content of that JSON file by downloading a website not the json file directly? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When I load a webpage; A javascript file within the page makes a request with headers that then generates the sources.json....like if you went to google maps - all the pins are being supplied via a json file that it's parsing but the JSON file isn't retrieved on page load. There is some sort of javascript function that sends my computers user-agent, that gets a response, and then has that

Comment: Can't you just request the JSON file directly instead. I assume you know the JSON url and it is static.

Comment: It's not static; its requested after you post headers to a URL and those headers are your user-agent (so you have to spoof a browser). The answer I posted below seems to work; what I am trying to do is not possible in PHP; it is possible with a javascript framework like PhantomJS

Comment: Can you post the url to the website? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Ill message it to you; I dont want to expose this websites stuff publicly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a post that answers this. I can use something like PhantomJS to emulate a browser environment apparently.

[php file_get_contents - AFTER javascript executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214122/php-file-get-contents-after-javascript-executes)