# How can I parse html that includes javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server side browser that can execute JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142271/server-side-browser-that-can-execute-javascript)
>   [Execute javascript in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php)

How can I parse HTML that includes JavaScript code, preferably with PHP script if possible.

As an example:

```
<a href="javascript:link(10, true);">link</a>
```

should be replaced by the appropriate value the JavaScript function returns, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>
```

A more complex example would be a saved facebook html page which is littered with loads of javascript code.

Summarized:
Return a DOM for a page with html+javascript

Comment: How about http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: @Adnan that doesn't interpret JavaScript as the OP wants

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible in the general case. What if for example the `link` function uses the user's mouse coordinates to decide what link to make?

Comment: Indeed, simplehtmldom ignores javascript code.

Comment: @Vatev, well thats not the case here

Comment: So, you want to parse the HTML string with PHP, but then additionally interpret the JavaScript code? Do you have a JavaScript interpreter on your web-server?

Comment: @Pekka, so he basically wants to read the Javascript code in the page, then execute the function calls and get return values. All of which with PHP. Good luck!

Comment: Where do you store the HTML-code?

Comment: @Adnan I didn't say it's easy. Just that a DOM parser isn't the answer here :)

Comment: and [Server side browser that can execute JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2142271)

Comment: @Pekka, true. Next time I'll pay more attention to the question :)

Comment: @xtra it was just an example. There is no possible way to tell for sure what the `link` function will do without all the context that a browser creates.

Comment: Just use mobile version of the website.

Comment: @Pekka, of course it can. I think Google is doing it to crawl those illusive Javascript navigation "links", right?

Comment: @Adnan SimpleHTMLDom does *not* execute JavaScript.

Comment: @Pekka, easy easy.. I meant about the server side browser :D

Comment: @Adnan it may crawl some of them but that does not solve the general case (which a library would have to). Also it will be very difficult to create even a partial solution (you will need a JS interpreter and half of a browser).

Comment: Would there be any possibility to emulate browser environment? e.g. in PHP execute like function open_page(http://google.com) and it would render both js as a browser and save html conent as a text file?

Comment: @xtra, Pekka already gave you **2** links about that.

Comment: @Adnan, yes but those are in java.

Comment: Those are not in Java. Did you even read them?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I was looking at wrong link.

Comment: can u post ur link function so i can make my answer perfect for u

Comment: @Shawn31313 there is no function, it was just an example. The point is it should 'render' all JS functions to html. Just like a modern browser does when you fully load a page.

Comment: haha, then that isnt going to work and would be `far` more difficult

Answer (score 1):

You could just give this link an ID. Not that this solution is javascript, jQuery.

So give the link an Id, or class.

```
$('.link').each(function() {
    var functionName = 'link';
    var start = $(this).attr('href');
    remove = start.replace('javascript:', ''), 
        get = remove.replace(new RegExp('^'+functionName+'\(((.+\,?)+)\)\;?', 'g'), function(a, b, c) {
        return c.replace(/[()']/g,'')
    }), args = get.split(",");

    //read settings
    var firstArgument = args[0];
    $(this).attr('href', firstArgument)
});​
```

Please note this is just an example.

Usage:

```
​<a class="link" href="javascript:link('http://facebook.com')"​>Hi</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

That would make the actual link http://facebook.com.

Adding new arguments this way is difficult though and its not really professional.
But this should do what you want, I just didn't know what your link function actually doesnt so I didnt add the argument with the boolean. Of course this could get far more complex and you could write a function that could do this too but I just wrote this for your really quick.

Check out the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/JvNea/1/).

Comment: This answer is useless for links built dynamically from functions or through even more complex structures such as JQuery. Also it only preg_matches the link out it does not actually execute the JS code to get the final link as such if `link()` didn't take any params this code would reutrn nothing as shown in the users own example: `<a href="javascript:link(10, true);">link</a>`

Comment: It gets the final link. Maybe not like the OP did it but that because I didnt know what their link function actually does. This was just an example and you can make it work for dynamically added links.

Comment: And that is the #1 problem, in order to understand the JS must be evaled to get the variable content return.

Comment: Also why would facebook or someone put a function into the `href` attribute of a link with it's param being that of the target link? One reason could be for outbound proxies to protect users from malicious content (`l.php' in this case for fb) but then this function still wouldn't return that proxied link but instead the initial potentially unsafe param that was entered. That's why I don't really see how this answer would work.

Comment: Now to take the example the OP posted: http://jsfiddle.net/Sammaye/H3qNW/

Comment: Yes, and thats what im saying. This was just an example, i dont know if you didn't get that. I didn't make it like their function since I dont know what their function even does. If I knew what his function did of course I could make the function. smh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14596/discussion-between-shawn31313-and-sammaye)

Comment: Im not gonna get into a drawn out convo about it. We know the signature of the function: `javascript:link(10, true);` and we know the return `http://www.example.com`. In order for your answer to work it has to get the return of the function as the href as such you must eval the function to get the return there is NO other way due to possible variable assignment which regex just could not accomplish...Your answer simply does not work for the question. Think of Google's own ability to spider AJAX apps, that is what he is closely trying to accomplish here I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When clicked, `javascript:` URIs just call the function and let it do whatever it wants (which MIGHT include navigating somewhere); they don't expect or use a return value. In many use cases, the function may not cause any navigation at all.

Comment: Hey, it's just an example, my point is to render javascript as html

Comment: There's a world of complexity in *"render javascript as html"* that I don't believe you comprehend.

Comment: What @Michael says. This is a *huge* task.

Comment: Yes, this would be far more complex then you think.

Answer (score 0):

DomDocument can be used to parse HTML in PHP including JS: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

You can "render" the JS with the HTML by merely echoing out the output of a cURL or wget (or whatever you use) without escaping the HTML characters. For external JS you are going to need to build a crawler which will crawl the `DomDocument` `script` tags and fetch the appropiate URL and load it into a position that is accessible unless you use it directly from their servers but I don't think they will be too happy about that.

Edit: My new answer after some comments is: no

Comment: @Adnan Where? I am unsure what you mean

Comment: I think what @Adnan means is 'since when does DomDocument parse JS?'.

Comment: JS is basically the textual content of a HTML tag/attribute as such (the last time I used it) script tags were accessible from DomDocument. I mean he just wants the JS with the HTML from what I see in his question. He does not actually want to parse the JS in a manner which will allow syntax highlighting...

Comment: @Sammaye, get ready for it! Apparently he wants to _execute_ the Javascript too.

Comment: Actually that is exactly what he wants. He wants to convert `javascript:...` URLs into 'regular' URLs.

Comment: Crazy might be a bit strong here, but my guess is he doesn't fully understand the complexity and context required to interpret those links.

Comment: @Vatev Indeed he does not, he would need integrate a JS engine directly since the JS can be executed in so many ways the only way is to hook into the actual link redirect event that a browser normally fires beore it moves to the next link which means he would need to build his own eval sandbox into JS or possibly PHP. To make it all work is insane, hence why Google doesn't do it, well or at all...

Comment: My head starts to hurt when I think about what one would have to do to achieve this... So I try not to think about it :)

Comment: Check out my answer, i think it should help.

Comment: @Sammaye, Google IS doing it. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/68/admin_crawl/AdvancedTopics#javascript) and [this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fi/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html)

Comment: @Adnan Aha yes this was part of their AJAX support I remember now. Though I have noticed they are very specific with what they support...

Comment: @Sammaye, they should be, otherwise they're open to some DDoS with some `while(true)`