# How to use curl get HTML code of webpage that include ajax(lazy load)?

Tags: curl

I use curl to get html code of webpage for server side.

This is a part of my code

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url); 
   curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
   curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $this->binary);
```

but it can not get html code that include ajax or somthing like this [web page](http://www.mayuki.com.tw/showProduct.aspx?p=3006374).

**look at** `<div id="pdImgs"></div>`

when I use my script it show nothing in that but the truth it has html code between div.

How can I get that by curl or other?

Comment: same, anyone has any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse html that includes javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711164/how-can-i-parse-html-that-includes-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag  is loaded dynamically by the Javascript or AJAX. So the Tag is empty in source code.
Since curl can not execute javascript which would be needed to load data asynchronously. Thus you get the tag empty.